# Summary of R function without the matched call

Tags: r, function

I wonder if it is possible to not show only `Call:` with formula in `R` functions.

```
require(graphics)

## Annette Dobson (1990) "An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models".
## Page 9: Plant Weight Data.
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)
```

**Output**

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ group)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-1.0710 -0.4938  0.0685  0.2462  1.3690

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   5.0320     0.2202  22.850 9.55e-15 ***
groupTrt     -0.3710     0.3114  -1.191    0.249
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6964 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.07308,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02158
F-statistic: 1.419 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.249
```

Comment: Are you saying you *dont* want the `Call:` in the result?

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven for your interest in my problem. Yes I don't want to show `Call: lm(formula = weight ~ group)` in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
ss <- capture.output(summary(lm.D9))
cat(ss[-(1:3)],sep="\n")
```

(More generally you could try do something fancy with `grep()`ing "[Cc]all" in the output and excluding that line and the subsequent line ...) Otherwise you'd have to hack `stats:::print.summary.lm`, e.g.

```
pp <- stats:::print.summary.lm
body(pp) <- body(pp)[-2]
pp(summary(lm.D9))
print.summary.lm <- pp
summary(lm.D9)
```

(Note that this is rather fragile; it depends on the `Call:` printing being the first line of the body of the function, and nothing in that line being necessary to the rest of the function.)

Comment: This is pretty sweet. :)